# How to create a JFrame within a Java applet or vice versa

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe

I am trying to create a Java applet with JInternalFrames.  For this I believe you need a JFrame in one form or another. I heard you could wrap your applet in a JFrame, is that best? If you could tell me what I should do I would appreciate it. TYIA -Roland

```
/**
 * @(#)rebuiltgui.java
 *
 * rebuiltgui Applet application
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2013/1/21
 */

import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class rebuiltgui extends JApplet {

    public void init() {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {

   // This is where I would put the internal frames.
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach is correct. In your `createAndShowGUI` method create a custom JFrame (you can create a custom class extending JFrame). In that JFrame do whatever you want.

Comment: Yeh, but I want a JFrame that cannot scoll outside of the applet

Comment: That wont happen, you are essentially talking about creating your own custom dialogs which are visible inside applet drawing area.

Comment: can you provide me with some source?  I can't really visualize what you are saying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create JFrame in the applet code same way you do in a stand alone Swing application:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");
....
frame.show();
```

The frame will leave the browser window, showing up as a separate window, just it will contain some warning tags that this is a Java applet running. Such frame can be resized or moved around.

Actually, some "applets" do not show much more than a single button to launch the frame in they main view.

See http://baba.sourceforge.net/ for an example of the applet that shows four buttons to launch four different visualizations (source code is available).

If, very differently, you actually want frames that could not leave your applet area, use [InternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html). It is a LayeredPane so you can also put your main component as a background layer.

Comment: Yeh, nice answer but I was hoping to keep it on the browser in an applet

Comment: I heard you can use context panes or something

Comment: And my applet cannot be resized

Comment: The applet area in a browser is generally not very big as various other content must still be around. But if you have some tremendous applet and need multiple floating frames there (plus some background content), InternalFrame should be capable of doing this.